# Python-based Socket program accept by libPcap(C-based)

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, pcap

Dear all:

I use **python-based socket client** to send string data (i.e log data).

On the other hand, I use **libpcap to sniff string data on the server side**.

## But I got an error on the client side when I send string data to the server side at the second time.

The error like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./udp_client_not_sendback.py", line 21, in <module>
    s.sendall(data) #Send UDP data
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

And below are my codes on the client and server side:

***Client side(Python)***

```
import socket, sys

host = sys.argv[1] #Server IP Address

textport = sys.argv[2] #Server Binding Port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #socket

try:
    port = int(textport)
except ValueError:
    port = socket.getservbyname(textport, 'udp')

s.connect((host, port)) #connect

while(1):
    print "Enter data to transmit:"

    data = sys.stdin.readline().strip() #UDP data

    s.sendall(data) #Send UDP data
```

***Server side(C libpcap)***

```
    pcap_handler_func(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *h, const u_char *bytes)
    {
    char timebuf[64];
    char addrstr[64];
    struct ether_header *ethhdr = (struct ether_header *)bytes;
    struct iphdr *ipv4h;
    struct ip6_hdr *ipv6h;
    
    memset(timebuf, 0, sizeof(timebuf));
    if (ctime_r(&h->ts.tv_sec, timebuf) == NULL) {
    return;
    }
    timebuf[strlen(timebuf) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("%s, caplen:%d, len:%d, ", timebuf, h->caplen, h->len);
    ipv4h = (struct iphdr *)(bytes + sizeof(struct ether_header));
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ipv4h->saddr, addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));
    printf("src[%s]\n", addrstr);

    return;
    }

    int main()
    {
    pcap_t *p;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char cmdstr[] = "udp";
    struct bpf_program bpfprog;
    
    p = pcap_open_live("eth1", 65536, 1, 10, errbuf);

    //Filter
    if (pcap_setfilter(p, &bpfprog) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", pcap_geterr(p));
    return 1;
    }

    //Packet action
    if (pcap_loop(p, -1, pcap_handler_func, NULL) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", pcap_geterr(p));
    pcap_close(p);
    return 1;
    }

    pcap_close(p);
    return 0;
    }
```

I think the problem is I don't bind the socket on the server side and I just use pcap to capture the string data.

So at the second time it happened the socket error on the client side.

Anyone can give me some suggestion to overcome this problem?

Thanks a lot for your helping.

Comment: Each time you run your client it reconnects to the server. Your server isn't ready for multiple connections (I think).

Comment: I'm assuming the infinite print loop in the python part is copy-paste error, and not really there?

Comment: Remember that there has to be an actual server running on the server side - I don't think `libpcap` will capture any data coming in on the NIC even when it's not passed to an open port. (Except maybe if using promiscuous mode or raw sockets or maybe the two are related.) If your server (which you haven't included) is coded to only accept one connection then quit, that would explain the behaviour.

Comment: Dear amaurea:
Yes, it's copy-paste error.

Comment: Dear millimoose:
But I think libpacp has the capability of promiscuous mode, because it's implementd by AF_PACKET. And I really capture the string data by the first time, but the socket error for the second time. What can I do when I don't want to use socket binding at the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libpcap, and the capture mechanisms it uses, are ***NOT*** intended for use when writing TCP/UDP/IP servers!  They're intended to 1) allow passive capture of packets and (in some cases and with newer versions of libpcap) injection of packets and 2) user-mode implementation of protocols that run atop the link layer and that don't have an implementation in the OS kernel.

If you have a process running on some machine, listening for packets using libpcap, that will ***NOT*** create a socket on that machine to receive packets sent to some particular TCP or UDP port.

The first time your program tries to send a packet to the UDP port in question, the machine to which you're sending it probably sees that it's being sent to a UDP port on which no socket is listening, and sends back an ICMP Port Unreachable message.  The send call has already been done; UDP is a connectionless protocol with no reliable delivery guarantees, so a UDP send does *NOT* wait for a reply of any sort - if the packet made it out onto the wire, that's considered "success", as no other checks for successful delivery can be made at the UDP level.

However, as you connected the socket in the client program, the client machine's ICMP implementation, if it sees the ICMP Port Unreachable message, will set an indicator on the socket to tell the program that the *previous* UDP packet couldn't be delivered (as there was nothing to which to deliver it).  A receive attempt on that socket - or, it appears, a subsequent attempt to send a packet on that socket - will return the "connection refused" error as an indication that the *previously-sent* packet couldn't be delivered.  It will also mean that the second attempt to send the packet won't actually send the packet; you'd have to make *another* attempt, which will, I think, succeed in sending the packet, although it will again get an ICMP Port Unreachable if there's no program listening for that UDP port on the server.

So *that's* why you saw the first packet, but not the second, in your sniffer (***NOT*** server!) application using libpcap.

So millimoose is 100% correct when he/she says "there has to be an actual server running on the server side".  Write one - using regular sockets, not libpcap and whatever mechanism it might use (AF_PACKET sockets on Linux, BPF devices on *BSD and OS X, etc.), and run it on the server machine.  You can *also* run your libpcap-based *sniffer* program, or some other sniffer program such as tcpdump or {Wireshark, TShark}, at the same time to see what's going on the wire.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I got know for my problems.  But I'd want to ask if is it possible to send the string data that I don't need to binding the IP address at the server side?  Because I need to do packet redirection which the server side will get the packet which doesn't belong to it ( It means the packet fields doesn't match to to the server side, such as IP address, MAC address ). Thanks.

Comment: ICMP Port Unreachable messages will be sent by the server unless there is a process running on the server that's bound to the UDP port number in question.  If you can't run such a server, you will have to have the client program somehow not have problems with those messages - for example, *not* connecting the socket in the client, and using the Python equivalent of `sendto()`, whatever that might be, *MIGHT* do that.

Comment: Dear Guy:
Thanks for your replying, your suggestion really works well.